# Search string based on length of parameter and start of path

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Could some one help with my search string. I have apth like 1-1-1 and there could be 10-20-1 and i only want to select the first character based on the parameter length e.g if i pass in 10 it will only select the Path_String 10 that begin with 10 or it was 1 it would select the Path_string Starting at 1

```
SELECT ID, AddedBy, Title, Path_String FROM MyTable
WHERE Path_String Like '%' + @Paramter + '%'; this isn't what I want.

DECLARE @dash varchar(2)
set @dash = NCHAR(8211)
DECLARE @Posts Table(PostID int, AddedBy nvarchar(50), Title varchar(100), Path_String varchar(max));
INSERT INTO @Posts 
SELECT PostID, AddedBy, Title, Path_String FROM Posts WHERE Path_String Like  @threadID + @dash + '%';
```

SELECT * FROM @Posts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go. this will solve your problem.DECLARE @dash  varchar(2)

```
set @dash = NCHAR(8211)

SELECT ID, AddedBy, Title, Path_String 
FROM MyTable 
WHERE Path_String Like  @Paramter + @dash + '%';
```

Comment: try your approach with this where clause. WHERE SUBSTRING(Path_String, 0, (Len(@threadID) - 1)) = @threadID;

Comment: it thats darn bloody character '-' when i changed it to '/' it works. Thankyou for help I wouldn't of found out without you're help. i''l mark as answered. thanks for help i appreciate it

Answer (score 3):

Remove the first % sign and that should do the select starting everything from your parameter and ending whatever it ends with.

It has also worked in the following way after giving it a thought.
And the '-' was not a problem there.

1.The exact match

```
declare 
@n varchar(3)
set @n='12'
select * from t
where SUBSTRING(t,0,CHARINDEX('-',t)) = @n

t
----------
12-12-12
12-13-14
12-13-14
```

2.Based on the length of parameter:

```
declare 
@n varchar(2)
set @n='12'
select * from t
where len(SUBSTRING(t,0,CHARINDEX('-',t))) = len(@n)

t
----------
12-12-12
22-22-22
33-33-33
31-31-31
12-13-14
12-13-14
```

---

Cheers

Comment: but if i pass in just 1 instaed of 12 or 13 i get 12 and 13 where i just want 1

Answer (score 1):

```
here use string methods to get index and substring to parse. i didn't execute this so fix the error you encounter. atleast this will give you an idea.

SELECT ID, AddedBy, Title, Path_String 
FROM MyTable 
WHERE Path_String Like @Paramter + '-%';
```

Comment: sorry. looks like i miss understand. i thought ur @parameter is 10-10-1 or so forth. in that case sergey benner is correct. just take first % sign out.

Comment: I got an error. Msg 537, Line 13 Invalid length parameter passed to the LEFT or SUBSTRING function.

Comment: when i use '-%' i get no results

Comment: what was your @paramter? try select @paramter + '-%' before executing query to see what it returs.

Comment: i passed in 13, 12  and tried 1 my paramter type is varchar(max) it returns 12-%

Comment: can you try this oneSELECT ID, AddedBy, Title, Path_String  
FROM MyTable  
WHERE Path_String Like '12-%';

Comment: I get nothing. you're first approach was almost right have a look at the error in the second comment

Comment: i wondor what is your path_string looks like. can you tell me result of SELECT TOP 1 Path_String from MyTable.

Comment: oh and first approach was based on input 10-10-1 and parsing 10 out of it.

Comment: my paths can go like this 1-1-1, 10-1-1 or 12-1-1 it's the start of the path that i want equal to the parameter so if i pas in 10 the path must be equal to the start 10 not the first character. I don't get any error top 1 in Path_string = 3 when i have 12 and 13

Comment: i am wondering it has something to do with '-'. try this. SELECT ID, AddedBy, Title, Path_String 
 FROM MyTable 
 WHERE Path_String Like  @Paramter '-1%';

Comment: i was right . here look at this . http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2785805/hyphen-vs-dash-replace-dash-with-hyphen

Comment: I get no results. what about this the second substring needs work though this is an Idea i don't know substring and charIndex yet. WHERE SUBSTRING(Path_String, 0, Len(@threadID)) =  subString(@threadID, Len(@threadID), (charIndex('-', @threadID) - 1));

Comment: how do i put in the right dash in stead of copying and pasting

Comment: WHERE SUBSTRING(Path_String, 0, (Len(@threadID) - 1)) = @threadID;